# Android Gradle plugin update from 3.1.4 to 3.2.0 cause TaskExecutionException

Tags: android, gradle

When I upgrade gradle plugin from 3.1.4 to 3.2.0, I'm facing the following error. What I did :

- uncheck Instant Run
- Add to local.properties 
  `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`
- Invalidate and restart
- Clean and Build project

No changes...

The error :

> build failed  32 s 17 ms
>   ...
>   :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForAndroid50SncfDebug
>   Execute transform

```
    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForAndroid50SncfDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:427)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 49 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.getInitalGraphData(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:162)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.makeDesugaringGraph(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:130)
    at com.google.common.base.Suppliers$NonSerializableMemoizingSupplier.get(Suppliers.java:160)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.getDependenciesPaths(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:231)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.getD8DesugaringCacheInfo(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:461)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:375)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitModule(ClassVisitor.java:148)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:731)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:632)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:144)
    at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyzeJar(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:92)
    at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:63)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.lambda$getInitalGraphData$4(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

My Project Level Gradle File

```
apply from: 'buildsystem/ci.gradle'
apply from: 'buildsystem/dependencies.gradle'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {

    ext {
        androidVersionCode = 15480001
        android40VersionCode = 15480001
        android42VersionCode = 17480001
        android50VersionCode = 20480001
        androidVersionName = "4.8.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        testApplicationId = 'my.package'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    description 'Creates the gradle wrapper.'
    gradleVersion '2.14.1'
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

repositories {
    google()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}
```

And my Module level grade file  :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    def globalConfiguration = rootProject.extensions.getByName("ext")

    flavorDimensions "flavor1", "flavor2"

    publishNonDefault true
    compileSdkVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidCompileSdkVersion")
    buildToolsVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidBuildToolsVersion")

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidMinSdkVersion")
        targetSdkVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidTargetSdkVersion")

        versionCode globalConfiguration.getAt("androidVersionCode")
        versionName globalConfiguration.getAt("androidVersionName")

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('../keystore/my.keystore')
            storePassword "PASSWORD"
            keyAlias "ALIAS"
            keyPassword "PASSWORD"
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] // This prevents the auto generation of Android.mk
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

    }

    productFlavors {
        android40 {
            minSdkVersion 15
            versionCode globalConfiguration.getAt("android40VersionCode")
            dimension "flavor1"

        }
        android42 {
            minSdkVersion 17
            versionCode globalConfiguration.getAt("android42VersionCode")
            dimension "flavor1"
        }
        android50 {
            minSdkVersion 20
            versionCode globalConfiguration.getAt("android50VersionCode")
            dimension "flavor1"
        }
        test{
            dimension "flavor2"
            applicationId = "my.package.test"
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

    lintOptions {
        quiet true
        abortOnError false
        ignoreWarnings true
        disable 'InvalidPackage'            //Some libraries have issues with this.
        disable 'OldTargetApi'
        //Lint gives this warning but SDK 20 would be Android L Beta.
        disable 'IconDensities'             //For testing purpose. This is safe to remove.
        disable 'IconMissingDensityFolder'  //For testing purpose. This is safe to remove.
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}

dependencies {
    def appDependencies = rootProject.ext.appDependencies

    // Dépendances Google
    api appDependencies.appcompatv7
    api appDependencies.supportv4
    api appDependencies.supportdesign
    api appDependencies.multidex
    api appDependencies.constLayout
    api appDependencies.playLocation

    // Annotations
    api appDependencies.dagger
    annotationProcessor appDependencies.daggerCompiler
    api appDependencies.bknife
    annotationProcessor appDependencies.bknifeCompiler
    compileOnly appDependencies.lombok
    annotationProcessor appDependencies.lombok

    // Librairies externes
    api appDependencies.commonsNet
    api appDependencies.commonsIo
    api appDependencies.altbeacon
    api appDependencies.rxjava
    api appDependencies.rxAndroid
    api files('src/main/jniLibs/activation.jar')
    api files('src/main/jniLibs/additionnal.jar')
    api files('src/main/jniLibs/mail.jar')

    // Projets
    implementation project(':converter')
    implementation project(':data')
    implementation project(':zones')
}
```

Versions file :

```
androidBuildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
androidMinSdkVersion = 15
androidTargetSdkVersion = 28
androidCompileSdkVersion = 28
appcompatv7Version = "28.0.0"
supportv4Version = "28.0.0"
androidAnnotationsVersion = '28.0.0'
supportdesignVersion = '28.0.0'
multidexVersion = "1.0.3"
constLayoutVersion = "1.1.2"
butterknifeVersion = "8.8.1"

//Libraries
daggerVersion = '2.17'
javaxAnnotationVersion = '1.0'
javaxInjectVersion = '1'
commonsNetVersion = '3.3'
commonsIoVersion = '2.4'
jLayerVersion = '1.0.1.4'
altbeaconVersion = '2+'
rxjavaVersion = '2+'
rxAndroidVersion = '2.0.1'
firebaseVersion = '16.0.1'
lombokVersion = '1.18.2'
retrofitVersion = '2.1.0'
okhttpVersion = '3.5.0'
guavaVersion = '26.0-android'
gsonVersion = '2.6.2'
converteegsonVersion = '2.4.0'
playLocationVersion = '15.0.1'

appDependencies = [
        dagger        : "com.google.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}",
        daggerCompiler: "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}",
        multidex      : "com.android.support:multidex:${multidexVersion}",
        appcompatv7   : "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${appcompatv7Version}",
        supportv4     : "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportv4Version}",
        supportdesign : "com.android.support:design:${supportdesignVersion}",
        constLayout   : "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:${constLayoutVersion}",
        commonsNet    : "commons-net:commons-net:${commonsNetVersion}",
        commonsIo     : "commons-io:commons-io:${commonsIoVersion}",
        altbeacon     : "org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:${altbeaconVersion}",
        rxjava        : "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:${rxjavaVersion}",
        rxAndroid     : "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:${rxAndroidVersion}",
        firebase      : "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:${firebaseVersion}",
        lombok        : "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}",
        bknife        : "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${butterknifeVersion}",
        bknifeCompiler: "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${butterknifeVersion}",
        playLocation  : "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${playLocationVersion}"
]
```

**SOLVED - The Solutions :** 
(Thanks iGio90 to have opened the issue)

1 **The current proper solution (recommended):**  lombok V1.16.18 :

- lombok version to **1.16.18**
- add a "lombok.config" file in project root, with the line `"lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties = true"`
- add in my build.gradle 
  `"compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'"`

2- **The hacky gross solution (not recommended),** use gradle.properties

- Let all versions up to date (my lombok version was 1.18.2, gradle 4.6, gradle plugin 3.2.0)
- add the following line to your gradle.properties : 
  `android.enableD8.desugaring=false`
  When syncing, you get the wargning "The option setting 'android.enableD8.desugaring=false' is experimental and unsupported. The current default is 'true'". But anyway, all build OK after that.

For more explanations, see the issue there : 
https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1882

Comment: Post your app level gradle file

Comment: having the exact same issue!

Comment: subject updated with gradle files

Comment: did you figure out a solution for this?

Comment: Subject edited with the solution in its

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After one days of tests, since I had your exact same issue and the top level + module level gradle files looks very close to mine i've found out that removing lombok dependency would make it work. Still don't know exactly why this happens but looks like a problem that lombok devs should solve. I'm gonna open an issue on github as well

(edit)

issue opened and let's wait :D 
https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1882

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to remove Lombok dependency, but so far it's hard because I'm using it everywhere :).

Comment: yes i know..... today i did a commit to remove it..... 1300 lines++ for getter and setter -_- but i can't wait for the fix

Comment: Only after I removed lombok things started to get better :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in the Android Gradle Plugin that got fixed in `3.3.0-alpha01`. You can update to the latest plugin, `3.3.0-alpha13`, and that will fix your issue. For more details on why this error occurs, please see https://issuetracker.google.com/117374690.